# How to upload a small file through an ASP.net C# controller through a Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I am trying to implement a controller to upload a small file via IFormFile.  When I only have the IFormFile and string as parameters it works (see image #2).  When I add a command object it doesnt (see image #1).

```
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, string fileName, AddResumeCommand command)
    {
        return Accepted();
    }
```

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 5.6.3.

The Swagger UI looks like this:
[image]

Now the following works:

```
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, string fileName)
    {
        return Accepted();
    }
```

The Swagger UI is:

[image]

I would like the first screen to be able to look like the second where there is the "file selection".

Comment: I added the version info in the question, please check if it's okay with you! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to annotate my controller with [Consumes("multipart/form-data")] along with the following function definition:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] AddResumeFileCommand fileCommand) { }
```

where AddResumeFileCommand is:

```
public class AddResumeFileCommand
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }

    public AddResumeFileCommand( string fileName, IFormFile formFile)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        FormFile = formFile;
    }
}
```